# Adding and Subtracting Numbers as Strings

Tags: javascript, operator-overloading

I read the following on a question on SO:

> '7' + 4 gives '74', whereas '7' - 4 gives 3 in JavaScript

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The '+' operator is defined for both strings and numbers, so when you apply it to a string and a number, the number will be converted so string, then the strings will be concatenated:
'7' + 4 => '7' + '4' => '74'
But '-' is only defined for numbers, not strings, so the string '7' will be converted to number:
'7' - 4 =>  7 - 4 => 3

Answer (score 30):

`+` is the String concatenation operator so when you do `'7' + 4` you're coercing `4` into a string and appending it. There is no such ambiguity with the `-` operator.

If you want to be unambiguous use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/parseInt) or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/parseFloat):

```
parseInt('7', 10) + 4
```

Why specify the radix to 10? So `'077'` isn't parsed as octal.

Comment: Just in case: Use parseInt('7', 10) with the base parameter, so that '077' will not be mistaken as an octal integer.

Comment: Or... you could use `Number('077')` which somewhat acts like `parseFloat` and always treats strings as base 10.

Comment: You could also just use `+'7' + 4`

Answer (score 16):

The `+` operator is overloaded in JavaScript to perform concatenation and addition. The way JavaScript determines which operation to carry out is based on the operands. If one of the operands is not of class `Number` (or the `number` primitive type), then both will be casted to strings for concatenation.

```
3 + 3 = 6
3 + '3' = 33
'3' + 3 = 33
(new Object) + 3 = '[object Object]3'
```

The `-` operator, however, is only for numbers and thus the operands will always be cast to numbers during the operation.

Comment: gotta love the way java works and all the fun bugs it causes.

Comment: woops, meant javascript, typed java.

Comment: Nobody made a joke about weak typing here? That disappoints me.

Answer (score 2):

Because + is for concentration, if you want to add two numbers you should parse them first parseInt() and - sign is for subtraction

Answer (score 2):

The sign + in Javascript is interpreted as concatenation first then addition, due to the fact that the first part is a string ('7'). Thus the interpreter converts the 2nd part (`4`) into string and concatenate it.

As for `'7' - 4`, there is no other meaning other than subtraction, thus subtraction is done.